# Using infinitives like comer

Tags: españa, conjugación, español-neutral, infinitivo

I was told that using just the infinitive **comer** means `to eat`.

However, does this fact change when using the indicative, subjunctive, or imperative? I am not referring to making any changes to the verb with conjugations.

Comment: Comer always means to eat. However, I don't really understand your confusion, so I don't know if you need further explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No confundir el "**infinitivo**" (*Forma no personal del verbo que expresa una idea verbal de forma abstracta, sin concretar las variaciones gramaticales de voz, modo, tiempo, aspecto, número y persona*), con los modos verbales, ( **indicativo, subjuntivo, condicional e imperativo**), donde cada modo tiene uno o más tiempos y tiempos compuestos.

El uso del "**infinitivo comer**",  es totalmente distinto bajo los diferentes modos verbales.

---

Do not confuse the "infinitive" (*non-personal form of the verb that expresses a verbal idea in an abstract way, without specifying the grammatical variations of voice, mode, tense, aspect, number and person*), with the verbal modes, (**indicative, subjunctive, conditional and imperative**), where each mood has one or more tenses and compound tenses.

The use of the "**infinitive comer**" is totally different under the different verbal moods.

---